# how to foreach datasets in chartjs laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach, chart.js

I have a problem that I can't loop datasets chartjs in laravel.
below is my code in model

```
  public function umur($tanggal)
{
    return DB::table('riwayat')
        ->select('umur')
        ->where('tanggal_riwayat', $tanggal)
        ->groupBy('umur')
        ->get();
}

public function data_grafik($tanggal, $umur)
{
    return DB::table('riwayat')
        ->select('hasil_keputusan', DB::raw('COUNT(id_riwayat) as jml_riwayat'))
        ->where('tanggal_riwayat', $tanggal)
        ->where('umur', $umur)
        ->groupBy('hasil_keputusan')
        ->get();
}
```

this is my controller

```
$tanggal="2022-08-10";
$query = $this->m_dashboard->grafik($tanggal);
$dataa = [];
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $dataa['label'][] = $row->umur;
    $data_grafik=$this->m_dashboard->data_grafik($tanggal, $row->umur);
    foreach ($data_grafik as $value) {
        $dataa['label_1'][] = $value->hasil_keputusan;
        $dataa['jml_riwayat'][] = $value->jml_riwayat;
    }
}
    $data = [
        'chart_data' => json_encode($dataa),
    ];
    return view('admin.dashboard', $data);
```

this is my view

```
var cData = JSON.parse('<?php echo $chart_data; ?>');
         const labels = cData.label;
         const data = {
             labels: labels,
             datasets: [{
                 label: cData.label_1,
                 backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                 borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                 data: cData.jml_riwayat,
             }
            ]
         };

         const config = {
             type: 'bar',
             data: data,
             options: {}
         };
         const myChart = new Chart(
             document.getElementById('myChart'),
             config
         );
```

this is my output

[image]

and this is the ouput what I want

[image]

Thanks in advance and sorry for occasional english mistakes

Comment: I think you need to create 3 datasets (with label: 'Series x' and with 4 data items) and 4 labels ['umur 1 bulan', 'umur 2 bulan', 'umur 3 bulan', 'umur 4 bulan']

Comment: That's only the example. Label series x and labels umur that I take the data from the database. So the data is dinamic. But I can't foreach it . Only display 1 datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a `@foreach ... @endforeach` in blade.

```
...
datasets: [
    @foreach ($contacts as $contact)
    {
        label: {{ json_encode($contact->name) }},
        data: {{ json_encode($contact->data) }}
    }
    @endforeach
],
...
```

`$contact->name` should be a string like `'FirstName'`.
`$contact->data` should be an array like `[1,2,3,4]`.